# Calculo de edad

Tags: c#

Mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo un formulario que en el cual se llenan con varios datos, uno de ellos es la fecha de nacimiento "ddmmyyy" en ese formato sin guiones ni nada, y lo que tengo que hacer es una función que cuando un afiliado ingrese una fecha, la función realice un calculo, me muestre la edad y si la edad es mayor a 18 me despliegue una ventana que diga "es mayor a 18" 
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: y que llevas echo?

Comment: ya tengo el formulario con todos los campos, es decir el sitio ya esta terminado, funcionando y todo, pero el cliente quiere agregarle eso al formulario, cuando se agregue, yo lo pensé hacer con una función y pasarle como parametro la fecha de nacimiento pero hasta ahi llegué

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer algo como esto

```
public int CalcularEdad(DateTime fechaNacimiento)
{
    //Obtengo la diferencia en años.
    int edad = DateTime.Now.Year - fechaNacimiento.Value.Year;

    //Obtengo la fecha de cumpleaños de este año.
    DateTime nacimientoAhora = fechaNacimiento.Value.AddYears(edad)
    //Le resto un año si la fecha actual es anterior
    //al día de nacimiento.
    if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(nacimientoAhora) > 0)
    {
        edad--;
    }

    return edad;
}
```

entonces en tu form lo usas

```
DateTime fechaNacimiento = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFechaNacimiento.Text, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int edad = CalcularEdad(fechaNacimiento);

if(edad > 18){
   MessageBox.Show("es mayor a 18");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió de mucha ayuda, lo pude realizar!!!